# How to set desired value of drop-down-menu when opening html file by name of URL?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am creating a html file with xslt and filtering some rows with a drop-down-menu.

Is it possible to change the URL, read the name of the URL, compare it with all items in your drop-down-menu and set the correct one as the selected item of the drop-down-menu automatically? All this should only happen when first open the html file. Is this also possible for committing a parameter after the URL: something like "html_file.html -parameter" read the parameter in JavaScript and automatically select the desired item in the drop-down-menu?